# Importance of Axiom of Extension in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

As far as I understand, one importance of Axiom of Extension is the following:

Let $A=\{1,2,2,2,3,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$. then due to Axiom of Extension we can conclude $A=B$.

Is there any other importance of Axiom of Extension apart from the one I specified?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it establishes the connection between the statement "$a=b$" (identity of sets) and a statement in terms of the symbol "$\in$". Otherwise you could hardly ever, if at all, derive identity of sets from their properties as sets.

Comment: So it provides a tool to check equality between two sets $a$ and $b$ using the 1-ary relation $"\epsilon"$?

Comment: Here "identity" means equality and "objects" means set. Am I right?

Comment: @Saikat Yes, I said objects while meaning sets. Yes, it says that identity of sets is a statement in terms of the $1$-ary symbol around which the theory is built.

Comment: By "properties as sets" you mean their "defining properties". Am I correct?

Comment: $A:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: -1\le x \le 1\}$  and $B=\{sin(x): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, we could not have said $A=B$ without Axiom of Extension. Is this example ok?

Comment: @Saikat No, I mean properties "as sets". Set theory comes naturally with a language of well-formed formulae, namely: the ones in the form $x\in y$ and all the ones that result from those plus a finite iteration of rules: $$(\star)\land(\diamond)\\\neg (\star)\\ (\star)\lor(\diamond)\\ (\forall x)(\star)\\ (\exists x)(\star)$$ I mean the properties associated to these well-formed formulae.

Comment: Can you tell me, what properties are associated with these well-formed formulae? 1 example will be very helpful.

Comment: @Saikat $\in$ is a $2$-ary relation isn't it? We write $x \in y$, so two variables. And yes the example $A = \{x \in \Bbb R: -1 \le x \le 1\} = \{\sin(x): x \in \Bbb R\}$ is OK. You show two inclusions so we have equality. In FO logic $=$ can also be primitive, but here it's a defined notion.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yes I was wrong it is a $2-ary$ relation. I read that Axiom of Specification gives us in Set Theory there is no "Universe", i.e there is no such set which would contain all sets in it.

So my question is what would be the domain of the 2-ary symbol "$\epsilon$"?

Comment: @Saikat there is no domain: it’s a 2-ary relation, but a logical one not as a subset of a product.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Right. I think that's the reason "$\epsilon$" is an undefined thing in Set Theory.

Answer (score 1):

Another use of extension is to allow us to define sets like $\{x|\phi(x)\}$ for those $\phi$ for which our other axioms imply such a set's existence, e.g. those of the form $\psi(x)\land x\in y$ for some set $y$. So instead of merely saying $\exists S\forall x(x\in S\iff\phi(x))$, which would be consistent with multiple such $S$, we can with extension not only know this $S$ is unique but also refer to such an $S$.